# When I try to inject dependencies, an error has been occurs, which says Failed assertion: line 315 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null'

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, use-case

I have problem when I try to use get_it in flutter. I can't inject my  UseCase. I am trying to fix this error for 4 hours.

```
E/flutter (10227): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart': Failed assertion: line 315 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != 
null': Object/factory with  type GetInitSliders is not registered inside GetIt.
E/flutter (10227): (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt 
sl=GetIt.instance;
E/flutter (10227): Did you forget to register it?)
```

My usecase class is below:

```
class GetInitSliders implements UseCase<InitSlider, InitSliderParams> {
final InitSliderRepository repository;
GetInitSliders(this.repository);
@override
Future<Either<Failure, InitSlider>> call(InitSliderParams params) async {
return await repository.getInitSlider(locationId: params.id);
}
}

class InitSliderParams extends Equatable {
final int id;
InitSliderParams({required this.id});
@override
List<Object?> get props => [
    id,
  ];
}
```

And finally dependency injections are here:

```
final sl = GetIt.instance;

Future<void> init() async {
sl.registerLazySingleton<NetworkInfo>(() => NetworkInfoImpl(sl()));

sl.registerLazySingleton<UseCase<InitSlider, InitSliderParams>>(
  () => GetInitSliders(sl())); //!!
sl.registerLazySingleton<InitSliderRepository>(
() => InitSliderRepositoryImpl(
  networkInfo: sl(),
  remoteDatasource: sl(),
),
);
sl.registerLazySingleton<InitSliderDatasource>(
() => InitSliderRemoteDatasourceImpl(
  client: sl(),
),
);
}
```

I don't know what is the problem, I have already registered GetInitSliders

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Don't u forget to await 'init' function right before running the app? Check ur main.dart and main function there.

Comment: I looked for it, it is fine. I am calling the init function. Like this: await init()